# Can some one please suggest a proper CSS name to find this element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

[image]

I need to click on the above button just using

> CSSSelector

.
I have tried with ;

```
> IWebElement el4m =
> Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='button'][contain='Search']"));
> IWebElement el4m =
> Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='button'][innerText='Search']"));
> IWebElement el4m =
> Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='button'][textContent='Search']"));
```

But nothing works fine.
Can some 1 please advice me a correct `CSSSelector` for above button.

Comment: How can i know who make this as "-1" post :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting by visible text is only possible via *xpath*. That being said you can use the class selectors provided above, or create a more specific one, using the *onclick* parameter, i.e. :

```
By.CssSelector("button[onclick='new UserManagement().LoadExcelExportSearchResult();']")
```

If you want to stick with text, you need to capture all *button* elements and iterate a list of them, then select the one you want via `Webelement.GetText().Contains()` method.

Comment: This works so fine @Moro

Answer (score 1):

- `Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class*=buttondefault]"));`
  using wildcard selector (*) which means if the class attribute has
  this proprety at any place it will find this element or
- `Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class^=buttondefault]"));`
  using caveat selector to find elements starting with "buttondefault"
  attribute or
- `Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class=buttondefault]"));`
  using = to find elements having class attribute equal to
  buttondefault

Comment: This works fine. Thanks for the idea @Prome

Comment: I just edited the answer from @Astaqc Consulting .

Answer (score 1):

Hi **css selector does not support using contained text as a identifier :**

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors

you could use **xpath to find element using text**

In your case , **all your css locators are incorrect:**

1. the tag you are using is **button** and not input, so it should start
   with input
2. There is no attribute called "**type**" in your given element

**Valid format is :**

The valid format is **tag[attribute="value"]**

so in this case it would be

1. **button[class="buttondefault"]**
2. **button[class="buttondefault"][onclick="blabla"]**
3. **button.buttondefault[onclick="blabla"]** ( you can find element by class using **tag.classvalue** instead of **tag[class="classvalue"]**)

Comment: Thanks,This explain me lot.